# DynArraySize() works correctly only up to arrays of 649 integer elements

Tags: delphi, dynamic-arrays, rtti, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I experienced a RTTI-related problem in *Delphi 10.2 Update 2* and was able to track it down to a fewer amount of code (see below).

I have some `TPersistent`-descendant class `TMyObj` that publishes a property of type `TArray<Integer>`. When I recieve its value via `GetDynArrayProp()` and query its size via `DynArraySize()` this works only up to a size of exactly 649 elements. Above this special count some very big size value is returned.

Note, that my array is generated from an instance of `TDictionary<Integer,Boolean>`'s `Keys` property with its very own `ToArray` method.
I also tried to modify `TMyObj.GetDynArray` so that it returns a instance of `TArray<Integer>` directly and it worked correctly.
Thus, I think that could correlate in some mystical way.

**What is wrong with my use of `DynArraySize()`? What's behind this mystical behaviour of dynamic arrays?**

```
program RTTIPropDynArray;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.Classes, System.Generics.Collections, System.SysUtils, System.TypInfo;

type
  TMyDict  = TDictionary<Integer,Boolean>;
  TMyArray = TArray<Integer>;

  TMyObj = class(TPersistent)
  private
    FValues: TMyDict;
    function GetDynArray: TMyArray;
  public
    constructor Create(const ACount: Integer);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property DynArray: TMyArray read GetDynArray;
  end;

{ TMyObj }

constructor TMyObj.Create(const ACount: Integer);
begin
  FValues := TMyDict.Create;
  while FValues.Count < ACount do
    FValues.AddOrSetValue(Random(MaxInt), False);
end;

destructor TMyObj.Destroy;
begin
  FreeAndNil(FValues);
  inherited;
end;

function TMyObj.GetDynArray: TMyArray;
begin
  Result := FValues.Keys.ToArray;
end;

function Test(const ACount: Integer): Boolean;
var
  LInstance: TMyObj;
  LExpectedSize: Integer;
  LDynArraySize: Integer;
begin
  LInstance := TMyObj.Create(ACount);
  try
    LExpectedSize := Length(LInstance.DynArray);
    LDynArraySize := DynArraySize(GetDynArrayProp(LInstance, 'DynArray'));
    Result := LExpectedSize = LDynArraySize;
    if not Result then
      WriteLn(Format('Expected size: %d; DynArraySize: %d', [LExpectedSize, LDynArraySize]));
  finally
    LInstance.Free;
  end;
end;

var
  LCount: Integer;
begin
  Randomize;
  LCount := 1;
  while Test(LCount) do
    Inc(LCount);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: Your code is broken

Long answer:

The call to the getter is creating a new array (see `TEnumerable<T>.ToArrayImpl` in `System.Generics.Collections.pas`) which is being deallocated in the epilogue of `System.TypInfo.GetDynArrayProp` (put a breakpoint there and look into the disassembler - it shows `@DynArrayClear`). Since there is no other reference to this array its memory gets deallocated (if you step into `System.pas` further you will see that it eventually ends up in `_FreeMem`). That means every call to this function is returning a dangling pointer!

Now why do you get correct results in all prior calls? Coincidence - the memory has not been reallocated by anything else.

Two possible solutions come into mind that don't involve rewriting the getter:

- use the RTTI from `System.Rtti.pas` as `TValue` keeps the reference alive
- write your own version of `GetDynArrayProp` that keeps the reference alive - but you have to make sure to always call DynArrayClear after or you create memory leaks

Personally I would use the first one.